# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

below is my query.

```
alter Proc Rp_ByVehicleNo

@Vehicle_Number nvarchar(50),
@DateFrom datetime,
@DateTo datetime
as

select Vehicle_Number,Vehicle_Booking_Date,Time_From,Time_To,KM_Start,KM_End,
      Total,
      SUM(Total) as tot, Vehicle_Used_By,Cost_Code
 from mtblLog_Book
 where     Vehicle_Number=@Vehicle_Number and
    Vehicle_Booking_Date between @DateFrom and @DateTo
 order     BY Vehicle_Booking_Date
```

showing error

Column 'mtblLog_Book.Vehicle_Number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains an aggregate function `SUM(Total)` but isn't included `GROUP BY` statement. If you need SUM for all table you shouldn't include other field in the select list. Otherwise if you need group by these fields and calculate `SUM` you should add `GROUP BY Vehicle_Number,Vehicle_Booking_Date,Time_From,Time_To,KM_Start,KM_End,Total,Vehicle_Used_By,Cost_Code` to your query.